# My potentially helpful answer possibly lost due to bad question

Tags: discussion

Earlier, someone posted a "question" (I would hardly consider it that) that was basically him ranting on how he doesn't like how it's difficult to do *basic* tasks on Ubuntu such as getting the correct permissions to write to a USB and getting an email client to work properly, and the only question in there was when he slapped on at the end that he was going to continue to have this mindset unless, and I quote,

> I tried to escape the many frustrations of Windows but the sheer amateurishness of Ubuntu is driving me back. I doubt very much that I am alone in this.
>
> UNLESS, somebody here can prove me wrong or, better still, point me to a genuinely mature distribution.

I viewed this as an oppurtunity to try and broaden this person's perspective on the subject so I wrote a response that was aimed at convincing him (or anyone that viewed the page later on) that the Ubuntu was something that should be learned and doesn't have to be rushed due to frustration. I feel like the answer to the kind of mindset the original poster was having would be beneficial to people in a similar position. Here's the answer that I replied with:

> All Ubuntu distributions are like that in a sense due to the fact that Ubuntu, in nature, is highly rewarding if you use it correctly. The potential for so much more is there for many things, but you have to learn the syntax, environment, and in general about how the OS processes things. If you are having so much trouble doing basic tasks, I would recommend either dual-booting or keeping another computer with Windows for the basic tasks that you are familiar with and on the side you can practice using the Ubuntu environment until you feel comfortable as using it as your primary OS. No rush, just let yourself learn at the pace that you *want* to, not the pace that you're forced to.

Overall, I think it would hurt to have the question closed. Rather, somehow make it into some sort of archived post as reference to others who are in similar situations. Obviously, adjustments to tags and title would be needed due to the nature of the original question, but I really do think that it could be a good resource. Is there any way that I could accomplish that sort of result?

Comment: "Rather, somehow make it into some sort of archived post" - isn't that kind of what closing is? Everyone will still be able to see the question and your answer - it just means no one can post new answers.

Comment: Yes, I guess. The only thing is making it more accessible for people that have similar issues. I don't think anyone that searched for anything along the lines of "Why can't I do basic tasks in Ubuntu?" will get to this post in any way. But, that's a whole nother thing with search indexing and stuff for another time and place. Overall, yes, I'm fine with this. Thanks for being so responsive to this.

Comment: If you think your answer would be helpful, you should ask your own question and use that answer to answer it :) Then you can make sure the question is valid and it won't get closed. Much better that trying to answer someone else's rant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we close a question, we don't delete the thread, it just goes into a state where new answers to it cannot be posted.

This is as close to the "archived" state you're speaking of where it is still accessible.

(However, the original poster is free to delete the original question, in which case you would lose your answer)

---

Rants and rebuttals are not designed for a site like Ask Ubuntu, which is heavily Q&A driven.

Typically, discussion threads where rants and rebuttals and such should take place on a discussion forum, not a Q&A site.  We typically close rants because they don't actually ask a question that fits within the scope of Q&A and what we can handle on the site.  We also tend to close these 'rants' because they're contention points which can result in very lengthy arguments that don't need to take place here on this site.

I've closed the question because it *is* a rant, and is not answerable within the scope here.

Refer to the [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask) for what kinds of things should not be asked or posted here.  (Rants are included in this)

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback. Sorry for not putting this in the right section.

Comment: @OwenHines no, you're fine.  Meta is where we invite the community to ask questions about things like this.  THat said, we don't like rants to remain open for more answers, because there'll be too many different opinions, and no "answer" since a question was not asked.  This is typically why we close such questions, and though I acknowledge what you're saying about your question maybe getting "lost", it won't be deleted from the thread - it'll just remain there on a question that is now closed (because it's a rant, and not asking a question)

Comment: **EDIT** I didn't mean to put "right" instead of "wrong" in my original comment. I really do apologize for having this in the wrong section, especially since this is my first question.